# How to differentiate between MMS and SMS via any Message property given in Twilio

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, sms, twilio-api, mms

Would it is possible to identify that the Incoming and Outgoing message is SMS or MMS.

[image: Messaging price]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

An inbound MMS will have a request parameter `NumMedia` with a non-zero value, if the inbound message is just an SMS then it will have `NumMedia=0`.

For outbound messages, you will know whether they are MMS messages because you either [create the message with the REST API and provide one or more `MediaUrl`s](https://www.twilio.com/docs/sms/api/message-resource#create-a-message-resource) or you respond to an incoming message with a [`<Media>` element](https://www.twilio.com/docs/messaging/twiml/message#nouns).

If you are inspecting the messages later, using the REST API, [message resources have a `NumMedia` property](https://www.twilio.com/docs/sms/api/message-resource#message-properties) that will be non-zero if it is a media message.